# SOAP Request: Apex Callout error: System.CalloutException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: apex, api, callout, soap, authentication

I am sending the following and getting a "Not in GZIP format" error? I think it might be because I am sending Basic Auth when the external web service need just the login credentials you can see in the request. It does not provide a token for login. So I may need to modify the Auth type. Still unsure how to troubleshoot this one.

```
public class ClientInsertCallout {

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String name, String Id) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        String Account             = 'xxxx';
        String Username            = 'xxxx';
        String Password            = 'xxxx';
        String Serverpool          = 'xxxx';
        Blob headerValue           = Blob.valueOf(Account  + ':' +  Username + ':' + Password + ':' + Serverpool);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

        req.setEndpoint('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sagittaws/transporter.asmx');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody('Guid='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Id, 'UTF-8')+'&ClientName='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(name, 'UTF-8'));
        req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm hardly an expert on SOAP, but the error you're reporting seems pretty straightforward.

The endpoint that you're calling out to expects the message that you're passing to be compressed with gzip, and it's not detecting that you're giving a gzipped request.

From some basic searching, it looks like Salesforce will automatically handle this (compression) for you if you include an appropriate header, `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, or `Content-Encoding: gzip` in your request.

The solution may be as simple as adding the following line sometime before you send your request:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
```

**+edit:**

I failed to see the `req.setCompressed(true)` line. I'm not sure if calling that method will set the appropriate headers for you. If the webservice you're calling out to is expecting a header to indicate if the body is gzipped or not, then that might be what's causing your issues.

You may be able to include a simple debug line or two to check if the header is being set for you using `req.getHeader('Content-Encoding')`, though I've had issues in the past trying to get debugs from `@future` methods.

If it comes down to it, you could try `system.assertEquals('gzip', req.getHeader('Content-Encoding'))` to throw an exception if the header isn't being set.